# HTML/CSS3 Fliping images

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, flip

Trying to get a flip effect like the first box shown here http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php

Although atm all i get is the following which when hovered over just flashes a type of shadow [image: box]

This is the code im using...

HTML:

```
<div id="f1_container">
<div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
  <div class="front face">
    <img src="images/eventbox.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="back face center">
    <p>This is nice for exposing more information about an image.</p>
    <p>Any content can go here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#f1_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#f1_container {
  perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean sth like that. Adjust in the way you like .

```
#f1_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#f1_container:hover {
  perspective: 1000;
  transform: matrix(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0);
border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg);          
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the cross-browser and that you have to create a hover effect (mouseover)

Comment: This has resolved the rotation problem although how would i go about it revealing a separate image? Say image1 then when rolled over with mouse image 2 appears after a flip, thanks.